# What's the difference between setting prototype to an object and a function?

Tags: javascript

`Person` and `Me` are constructors:

```
function Person(){//define something here};
function Me(){};
```

Now what is the difference between

```
Me.prototype = Person;
```

and

```
Me.prototype = new Person();
```

?

Comment: `Me.prototype = Person` sets a reference to the original `Person` function. `Me.prototype = new Person()` sets a reference to a new instance of the original `Person` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Me.prototype`'s type is object.

You add methods to this object so they will be *attached* to *instances* of `Person`.

So ,  when should you use `Me.prototype = new Person();` ?

(for example) - When you want to check `instanceof` via polymorphism alike.

example :

```
function Ninja(){}

Ninja.prototype =new Person();

var n = new Ninja();

 n instanceof Person //true;
```

Comment: So, `function Me(){}; Me.prototype = new Person();` will have a different prototype from `function You(){}; You.prototype = new Person();`, right? And changing the prototype property on one side would not affect the other?

Comment: Not a bad way of explaining it

Comment: This is one quite incomplete.  You would also do it when you wanted a ninja to inherit the capabilities of a person.  But there are potential problems with `Ninja.prototype = new Person();` too if the `Person` constructor function does much of anything, which is why it's usually best done with one more level of indirection:  `function F() {}; F.prototype = Person.prototype; Ninja.prototype = new F();  Ninja.prototype.constructor = Person`.  Often this boilerplate is wrapped up in a function.  Or better yet, use `Object.create`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet preserving  the prototype chain is the main usage for my example.  ofcourse, there are other uages.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, I was assuming we wanted to preserve the prototype chain.  But if the Person constructor looked like, say `function Person(name) {this.name = name;}`, then your technique would mean that the Ninja prototype would include `name: undefined`.  And of course it would be worse if the constructor included `if (!name) {throw 'Name not supplied';}`.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of an object is also an object. `Person` is a function/constructor, while `new Person()` returns an object (person instance). 
Therefore, the simplest logical deduction is that the second assignment is doing what you 'd expect.

Now.. in js functions are also objects... this may be the cause of your confusion.
So, if point your object's prototype to a function :

```
Me.prototype = Person;
```

then your object will inherit the function's prototype, which is the Function *"class"* and it means that your previous assignment can be translated to:

```
Me.prototype = new Function();
```

which clearly is not what you want.
I hope that I made a point and that it will help you in the prototypal inheritance confusion.

Comment: I'm still confused in that, shouldn't prototype inherit EVERYTHING the `Person` function has, including anything specific on `Person`? Why does it only inherit to prototype part of `Person` function object in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Consider following code:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.foo = function () { return 'bar' };
function B() {}
function C() {}

B.prototype = A
C.prototype = new A()

b = new B()
c = new C()

console.log('b instanceof A', b instanceof A);
console.log('c instanceof A', c instanceof A);
console.log('b.foo && b.foo()', b.foo && b.foo());
console.log('c.foo && c.foo()', c.foo && c.foo());
```

It should tell you that doing `B.prototype = A` is wrong. Now reasons behind it is convention and implementation. Prototype of a Function is an instance of an object fields of object become methods and properties once Function is used as a constructor.